SharePoint GetChanges API do not update my action on SharePoint
the first I'm so sorry about my English, if you dont understand, please tell me.
I'm a beginner with Azure. Now I have an issue when working with SharePoint and Azure AD app.
I have created a Azure AD app and assign all SharePoint permissions to my app.
And in SharePoint, I also create new Document. When I do something like add new file, delete file, etc. The GetChanges API with this document is work fine.
An item that is in GetChanges API response
But when I use GetChanges on Shared Document (this document was created by other owner), before I also created, updated, and deleted some files. But the GetChanges API only returns the actions that happend before 8/3, like below
Newest action does not caputured, only show actions that happen before 8/3
This make I cannot use SharePoint webhook to capture what is new on my SharePoint.
So someone who meet this situation before, can you please give me some approachs for handling this?
Thank you so much!
I have created Azure AD, with use SharePoint API (GetChanges) + SharePoint webhook, but the newest actions on Share Documents can not captured.
Edit:
The error has been fixed, Microsoft supporter have checked the issue and said that there might be a delay for sometime.
[Issue closed]
